# Payments with Paypal

Tags: paypal, drupal-7

I want to do something simple: collect payments/donations with Paypal. I think that installing Ubercart is a bit heavy for something this simple. I want people to just go to the site and make a payment, possibly entering their email addresses so I can send them a thank you.

Which is the best Paypal module to use for this purpose with Drupal 7? If no module is available for 7, I'll install Drupal 6.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Paypal Donation module](http://drupal.org/project/paypal_donate) has a release for Drupal 7. The [lm_paypal module](http://drupal.org/project/lm_paypal) would also handle what you're wanting to do, but there isn't yet a Drupal 7 release.

Comment: Thank you Matt. I'm gonna check it out. Do you know if its possible to integrate with a thermometer of some sort? That's just an add on, but just wondering. Thanks much.

Comment: I doubt either one of them come with a thermometer out-of-the-box. I'm sure one could be added on though.

Answer (score 0):

The worked payment module in Drupal 7 is ecommerce module.

Comment: Up to now, only dev release for 7.x is available